# Selenium WebDriver not loading page after Firefox update

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I had a problem with Selenium (v. 2.48.0) and Java WebDriver after upgrading Firefox to version 45 (from 44) - it didn't load the page, it's freezing on Firefox start screen.

I know it is known issue, I have to upgrade my Selenium version to cooperate with new Firefox and it would be fine.
However, it isn't the solution for me, because I have to keep compatibility with older Firefox.
So I installed Firefox version 44 which was fine with my Selenium version before, but now the page isn't loading, same as with new version of Firefox.

Has anyone have the same problem and somehow solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade selenium to the [currently latest 2.53 version](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG) to avoid compatibility issues.

Or, if for some reason, you cannot upgrade, use an [older Firefox version](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/) (38 or older).

Comment: I forgot to mention - I would prefer to keep my Selenium version on 2.48, because upgrading could cause some compatibility problems in my pretty-big project.

Comment: Ye, I can't upgrade my Selenium version because of new errors I'm getting with new version on my particular tested page. It would be a problem for me with every upgrade, so I want to have one version of Selenium working with one specific version of Firefox, which should be fine.

Comment: @Rudik okay, you can also downgrade Firefox. Updated the answer.

Comment: That's right! Version 38 of Firefox works fine. But I'm wondering, why are versions (38; 45] not working correctly, while version 44 worked before upgrading to FF45.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that even if you downgraded to 44 it doesn't automatically update itself back to 45 after installing. Firefox automatically updates itself unless you uncheck that option from Options / Advanced / Update.

Comment: I prevent the automatically updates by settings flags `app.update.auto` and `app.update.enabled` in FirefoxProfile to `false`